# What event is generated when mouse is clicked outside a combo viewer when the drop down in seen?

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox, swt, jface

I have a `ComboViewer`. While the drop down is seen, I clicked the mouse outside the viewer (not in any part of the viewer). The first item in the drop down is populated in the box. What event is generated when this population happens?

I tried `SelectionChangedListener` on the comboviewer and  `FocusListener`, `KeyListener` and `SelectionListener` on the combo box of the viewer. None of this is helping.

My requirement is to enable and disable a button depending on what is present in the combo box. Combo empty, disable the button else enable it.

```
public class CartoonAnimalCombo {
public class Cartoon {
    private String firstName;
    private String type;

    public Cartoon(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.type = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new CartoonAnimalCombo();
}

private String inputText;

CartoonAnimalCombo() {

    Display d = new Display();
    Shell parent = new Shell(d);
    parent.setSize(250, 250);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    parent.setLayout(layout);

    Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Select a character:");
    final ComboViewer viewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.NONE);

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof Cartoon) {
                Cartoon person = (Cartoon) element;
                return person.getFirstName();
            }
            return super.getText(element);
        }
    });

    final Cartoon[] cartoons = new Cartoon[] { new Cartoon("Mickey", "Mouse"), new Cartoon("Donald", "Duck"),
            new Cartoon("Pluto", "Dog"), new Cartoon("Chip", "Squirrel"), new Cartoon("Dale", "Squirrel") };

    viewer.setInput(cartoons);
    final ArrayList<Cartoon> tempVar = new ArrayList<Cartoon>();
    final Combo combo = viewer.getCombo();
    combo.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.keyCode != SWT.ARROW_DOWN && e.keyCode != SWT.ARROW_UP && e.keyCode != SWT.CR) {
                tempVar.clear();
                String text = combo.getText();
                if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
                    setSearchText(text);
                    for (Cartoon var : cartoons) {
                        if (var.getFirstName().matches(inputText)) {
                            tempVar.add(var);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    tempVar.addAll(Arrays.asList(cartoons));
                }
                viewer.setInput(tempVar.toArray());
                combo.setListVisible(true);
                combo.setText(text);
                combo.setSelection(new Point(text.length(), text.length()));
            }
        }
    });
    Label lastName = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    lastName.setText("Type of Animal:");
    final Text textbox = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            if (selection.size() > 0) {
                textbox.setText(((Cartoon) selection.getFirstElement()).getType());
            }
        }
    });

    parent.open();
    while (!parent.isDisposed()) {
        if (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
            d.sleep();
        }
    }
    d.dispose();
}

public void setSearchText(String searchText) {
    if (searchText == null || searchText.isEmpty()) {
        this.inputText = ".*"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    } else {
        this.inputText = searchText + ".*"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In that case, a SelectionChangedEvent should be sent and propagated to your SelectionChangeListener. If it's not, then we can interpret it as a bug and you should report it to http://bugs.eclipse.org with the simplest steps to reproduce.

Comment: Added the code to reproduce it, just in case if anyone wants to take a look. The combo is searchable. Also reporting it.

Comment: @LaishramKrishnanandaSingh When I run your code and follow your instructions in the question, the first element isn't selected.

Comment: Type "M", you will see "Mickey" in the drop down. Now, click anywhere else except the combo. "Mickey" is populated, but the text box below show no changes. If I select any item in the drop down by clicking, it does reflect in the text box.

Comment: @LaishramKrishnanandaSingh Yeah, I can see what you mean now. I've added all the listeners that exist to it and I can see `SWT.Verify` and `SWT.Modify` being fired when entering the `M`, but when I click somewhere outside the combo, only `SWT.Paint` is fired with the new value, no selection, no nothing else. So your only chance seems to be using `SWT.Paint` and figuring out if it's actually a change event that's happening. But I'd definitely post this as a bug in the official tracker.